# Querying nested in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

i'm learning MongoDB for a few weeks now and i have still no idea how to query nested documents in my project. I read the MongoDB-docs and googled a lot, but i found no good explanations or tutorials for my problem. Maybe you can help me!

I have a Collection with the following structure (here the JSON output):

```
{
    community: "1",
    date: 1365680790125,
    isIndoor: "true",
    party: {
        teams: [
            {
                isWinner: true,
                players: [
                    {
                        name: "jim",
                        hits: 4,
                        isFinisher: true
                        },
                        {
                            name: "john",
                            hits: 6,
                            isFinisher: false
                        }
                    ]
                    },
                    {
                        isWinner: false,
                        players: [
                            {
                                name: "mike",
                                hits: 6,
                                isFinisher: false
                                },
                                {
                                    name: "moe",
                                    hits: 3,
                                    isFinisher: false
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                    },
                    id: "3141be7f9988d872"
                }
```

And now I want to get all records where 'jim' participated.

I tried this query (in coffeescript), but i get no results and i think its very crappy...

```
query = party:
$all:[
    teams: 
        $in: [
            player: [
                name: 'jim'
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

I hope you can help me understand querying nested documents.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) to query against the fields of embedded objects:

```js
query = { 'party.teams.players.name': 'jim' }
```

Comment: hey, thanks for answer! I tried your query on my database (deployd platform) and it is not working.. i get all records and not only the records with player-name 'jim'. Then I tried your query in the mongoDB Browser Shell and it worked...

Comment: okay... it is a bug in deployd. it works now, see: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/deployd-users/NidQ1sT9u6o/v8oGZZa0flsJ

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem, @rojan21, deployd return all records on any query, but I can't find information about this bug...